# Where to start with ChatBots?

Tags: python, nlp, lstm, bert, chatbot

I want to start my journey into ChatBots and how I can create them. I have read some articles regarding the type of chatbots. Basically there are 2 types of chatbots, one is a **rule based** and the other is a **NLP/ML based**. I am more interested in the latter and want some kind of started guide. I have read that these kind of chatbots usually use some kind of attention models (as they give state of the art results) like **BERT**. I have no experience in attention models. I have started with LSTM models and it's variations, as attention models have LSTM at their core I think.

What I want from the stalwarts in this field is some **advice/starter guide (be it articles/blogs/videos) on how to get started or am I going in the right direction or not.** It would really help a novice like me!

Thank you!

Comment: This is a good question nonetheless, it has been voted to be closed because according to someone, it needs details. I recommend you to add more information like the language you want and if possible, details on how do you think to apply it, industry, framework

Comment: @Multivac edited my question

Comment: Here's a simple chatbot using transfer learning and transformers: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/conversational-ai-chatbot-with-huggingface-transformers-in-python